# On display about my nikon whjich goes off each time i take a photo

Tags: digital-asset-management

Hey when am taking picture with my nikon d5300 it goes off.. I have to put it on again to see the image is it normal

Comment: Can you describe what display you are talking about? What do you want it to show? How are you taking the photo? (Are you using live view on the rear screen or the viewfinder?)

Answer (score 2):

Most DSLRs and other digital ILCs have user adjustable settings that determine if and for how long the preview image is shown after a photo is taken. In general, one can select anything from "no preview" to "Leave on until I press another button."

For the Nikon D5300, the options are accessed under [Main Menu → Playback Menu: Managing Images → Image Review].

Accessing the camera's menu is covered beginning on page 54 of the [*Nikon D5300 User's Manual*](https://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/J35vT000mUBp02YuZAn12zZBPl84/D5300VRUM_EU(En)02.pdf).